# How to print text inside of a html tag using lex

Tags: html, css, c, lex

```
 %{ 
 %}
%% 
"<"[^>]*> {printf("%s\n", yytext); }  
. ;
%%     

int yywrap(){} 
int main(int argc, char*argv[]) 
{ 
extern FILE *yyin = fopen("tags.txt","r");  
yylex();  
return 0; 
}
```

This prints out all the tags...how do i print the text inside of the tags.
i used   ">"[^>]*< but that didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Your lex file:

- Prints tags
- Ignores everything else

If I understand correctly, you want it to

- Ignore tags
- Print everything else.

That suggests that you should try swapping the actions in your current file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text between the tags, you need to ignore the tags and grab all other text that does not mark the begin of a tag:

```
TAG               <[^>]*>
ALLBUTSTARTOFTAG  [^<]*

%%

{TAG}              ;  // do nothing, i.e. ignore a tag
{ALLBUTSTARTOFTAG} {printf("%s\n", yytext); }  // print the text until a tag starts

%%
```

Then, the following function

```
int main(){
    char string[] = "before any tag<html>between html and body<body>body content</body>between body end and html end</html>after html end";
    YY_BUFFER_STATE buffer = yy_scan_string(string);
    yyparse();
    yy_delete_buffer(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
before any tag
between html and body
body content
between body end and html end
after html end
```